# PHP: String to array, check spelling, back to string (preserving special characters)

Tags: php, regex, spell-checking, string-conversion

I'm working on a custom spell checker (and learning as I go) that needs to do the following upon form submission:

1. Convert the string submitted from textarea into an array of words.
2. Search for each word in the array in the mysql `english` table.
3. If the word does not exist, mark it as misspelled by wrapping it in an HTML tag.
4. Convert the array back to a string including original punctuation, line breaks and the newly-tagged words.

I've searched many a post as well as php.net and I've come up with the following code that does everything except #4 and I've been stuck there for a couple days (I assume I need to add something in or before #1 for the preservation part but I can't seem to wrap my head around it):

Current code:

```
$inputContents = $_POST['compose'];
$inputContents = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z ']+/", ' ', $inputContents);
$inputContents = trim($inputContents);
$inputContents = preg_split("/\s+/", $inputContents);

var_dump($inputContents);

foreach ($inputContents as $singleWord) {
  $word_exists = mysql_query("SELECT `word` FROM `english` WHERE `word` = '". mysql_real_escape_string($singleWord) ."'") or die(mysql_error());
  $word_exists = mysql_num_rows($word_exists);
  if ($word_exists !== 0) {
    echo $singleWord ."&nbsp;";
  }else{
    echo "<span id='misspelledWord' style='font-style:italic;'>". $singleWord ."</span>&nbsp;";
  }
}

<form action="spellcheck_test.php" method="POST">
  <textarea name="compose"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Post!" />
</form>
```

Using the code above, if my string is:

`Spellling games; they're alot of fun!`

Then my array becomes:

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(9) "Spellling" [1]=> string(5) "games" [2]=> string(7) "they're" [3]=> string(4) "alot" [4]=> string(2) "of" [5]=> string(3) "fun" }
```

And the code outputs:

*Spellling* games they're *alot* of fun

But I'd like it to output:

*Spellling* games; they're *alot* of fun!

Any suggestions on accomplishing #4?

Comment: "id='misspelledWord'" should be a class as there may be multiple spelling errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1. you should use `explode(' ',$inputContents)` and you'll endup with:

```
{ [0]=> "Spellling" [1]=> "games;" [2]=> "they're" [3]=> "alot" [4]=> "of" [5]=> "fun!" }
```

Then create a new array `$checkedWords=array();` and take care of 2.

```
foreach ($inputContents as $singleWord) {
  //your MySQL checks here;
  //mysql_ functions were deprecated, use mysqli or PDO instead
  preg_match('/([a-zA-Z\']*)(\W*)/',$singleWord,$parts);
  //check parts[0] against MySQL here
  //$parts[1] is your word without other following chars
  //$parts[2] are any characters following your word
  if (isset($parts[2]) $parts[2]=''; 
  if ($word_exists !== 0) {
     $checkedWords[]=$parts[1].$parts[2];
  }else{
     $checkedWords[]="<span class='misspelledWord'>".$parts[1]."</span>".$parts[2];
  }
}
```

To get to 4. you'll just have to `implode(' ',$checkedWords)`

Comment: explode split string by one whitespace, so preg_split("/\s+/", $inputContents) is good move

Comment: @kirugan Thanks, I'll use that to account for line breaks.

Comment: @godka This is getting me close but the regex may need adjusting. It was putting just the first letter of each word into both $part[0] and $part[1], so I changed it to /([a-zA-Z\']**+**)(\W*)/ and now it's putting word+character in $part[0]:
`string(9) "Spellling" string(6) "games;" string(7) "they're" string(4) "alot" string(2) "of" string(4) "fun!"`
And word only in $part[1]:
`string(9) "Spellling" string(5) "games" string(7) "they're" string(4) "alot" string(2) "of" string(3) "fun"`
How I can alter the regex so $part[0]=word only and $part[1]=character only? Is that what you intended?

Comment: **+** was intended to make '+' bold. I only added the '+'.

Comment: forgot the star there. fixed it and the order of parts, check again

Comment: Awesome, almost there! One last part I just tested... using a string containing line breaks. Since I'm splitting the string by `/\s+/`, the line breaks are not being preserved. I'm going to try this: **1.** Split the string by `/\n+/` to get `$paragraphs`, **2.** Use a new `foreach()` to split each paragraph into words using `/\s+/`, **3.** Embed the current `foreach()` into the new `foreach()` to check spelling, **4.** `implode(' ',$checkedWords)` to restore paragraphs, **5.** `implode('/\n/',$paragraphs)` back together. Can you (@godka or @kirugan) think of a better way?

Comment: better split by `/\s+/m` the m there is for _multiline_. just know that \s matches any of the chars in the class [\r\n\t\ ] and you would forget where is which and just `implode()` with a space. did you try `explode()` first ?

Comment: Yeah, I re-tried explode() when I started trouble shooting the line break issue but it didn't seem to work as well. I'm sort of dancing around the solution, I can feel it... so I'll fiddle with it some more and come back Sunday or Monday, either to ask for further input or to present the full solution. If you get the itch then feel free to have a crack at it but you've already helped me a lot today, so thanks!

Comment: Got it. I'm accepting your answer and posting my final code below for anyone needing it in the future. If you see anything I can improve (like mysqli_ after I study up on it) then please let me know. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final code I ended up with. Made some slight changes during testing to fix problems.

```
if (isset($_POST['compose'])) {
  $inputContents = $_POST['compose'];
  $paragraph =     preg_split("/\n+/m", $inputContents);

  foreach ($paragraph as $singleWords) {
    $singleWords =   preg_split("/\s+/m", $singleWords);
    $combineWords =  array();

    foreach ($singleWords as $singleWord) {
      preg_match('/(["]*)([a-zA-Z\'-]*)([\W0-9]*)/',$singleWord,$parts);
      $word_exists =  mysql_query("SELECT `word` FROM `english` WHERE `word` = '". mysql_real_escape_string($parts[2]) ."'") or die(mysql_error());
      $word_exists =  mysql_num_rows($word_exists);
      $checkedWords = array();

      if ($word_exists !== 0) {
        $checkedWords[$singleWord] = $parts[1].$parts[2].$parts[3];
      }else{
        $checkedWords[$singleWord] = $parts[1]."<span class='misspelledWord'>".$parts[2]."</span>".$parts[3];
      }
    $combineWords[] = implode(' ',$checkedWords);
    }
    $reformParagraph[] = implode(' ',$combineWords);
  }
  $reformContents = implode("<br />",$reformParagraph);
  echo "<p>".$reformContents."</p>";
}
```

And the form...

```
<form action="spellcheck_test.php" method="POST">
  <textarea name="compose"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="submitPart" value="Post!" />
</form>
```